# Persistent connection between iOS app and Rails web service

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ios, web-services

I have some Rails web service, and iOS iPad app. This iPad app need to notifies web service about iPad's location in some interval (5s for example), and when something is happened web service need to send some data to iPad app.

I can notify iPad app with push notification about something, but I need permanent notification with data in notification (simple string).

Can you give me some advice or some sample how to solve this mystery for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've received the notification, why not make a quick call back to a Rails service to get a hold of whatever data you needed?  There's an extra server call, but if you're already polling around 5s, then this hit shouldn't be too big of a deal.

Hope that helps!  :-)

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand well. I have iPad and Rails web app (who need to be aware of iPad's location real-time). In some moment, rails app must to send some request from Rails app to iPad app, and get response about it. This request must be really quick.